# InStr start parameter suddenly begins with 0

Tags: excel, vba

I check all cells if there is a word like "ean". Afterwards, I would like to mark "ean" in the string red with the FontStyle bold. Everything works fine, but the problem is, that after i = 460, the pos is always 0. I did not find a restriction for the start-value of InStr.

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

Here my code:

```
 For a = 2 To lastRow
         Text = LCase(Cells(a, 11).Value)
         TextLength = Len(Text)
         If Text Like "* ean[!A-Za-z0-9]*" Then
             korrektur = TextLength Mod 3
             TextLength = TextLength - korrektur
             Iteration = TextLength / 3
                 For i = 1 To Iteration
                    pos = InStr((i * 3), Text, "ean")
                    Cells(a, 11).Select
                          With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=3).Font
                             .Color = vbRed
                             .FontStyle = "bold"
                         End With
                     End If
                 Next i 
      Next a
```

Any idea?

Greets, Yab

Comment: Can you please look again where you open IF and where you put your END IF. For sure you forgot some line like `If pos <= 0 Then`. Because for sure it can also happen that "ean" is not in the word.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
For a = 2 To lastRow
    Text = LCase(Cells(a, 11).Value)
    TextLength = Len(Text)
    If Text Like "* ean[!A-Za-z0-9]*" Then
        korrektur = TextLength Mod 3
        TextLength = TextLength - korrektur
        Iteration = TextLength / 3
            For i = 1 To Iteration
                pos = InStr((i * 3), Text, "ean")
                Cells(a, 11).Select
                With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=3).Font
                    .Color = vbRed
                    .FontStyle = "bold"
                End With
            Next i
    End If
Next a
```

The `End If` was inside the second `For-loop`!